# mysql remove and insert from text

Tags: mysql

column a contain below text.

**claim for my new  mercedes**

I'm trying to remove common `english words` like `for, my, new` from column and then split and insert remaining text in `2` other column.

**For example :**

`mercedes and claim will store in different column`

Need suggestion

Comment: how do you determine common english words? do you already have a logic?

Comment: i have list for common words in other table..

Comment: so also paste table structure, the sample data from both the tables, and for a better answer also provide the expected result :)

Comment: What client-side language are you using (php? java?). For what it's worth, the FULLTEXT indexing stuff in MySQL already has stopword (common word) suppression and search capabilities.

Comment: i am not using any client-side language..I trying to implement it in mysql

Comment: Can we break a string and save it to different columns..